# Java8 : Efficient approach to manipulate Map

Tags: java, java-8

I've two map of Map definitions as shared below, Based on the existence of one key from map1, I need to copy the entry to another map. Below code works as needed but is there any better and simple approach to achieve the same. Your suggestions are appreciated.

```
    Map<Object, HashSet<Map<Object, String>>> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Object, HashSet<Map<Object, String>>> map2 = new HashMap<>();

    map1.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> {
        Set<Map<Object, String>> infoMapSet = e.getValue();
        infoMapSet.forEach(
                inMap -> {
                    if (inMap.containsKey("isMerge")) {
                        Set<Map<Object, String>> set = new HashSet<>();
                        set.add(inMap);
                        map2.put(e.getKey(), set);
                    }
                });
    });
```

Comment: My suggestion is to rethink your data model design. No approach will be easy to understand with a map of sets of maps.

Comment: Anouti, completely agree with you... But that was legacy design. Need to think on re-modelling of the data model design

Comment: This code seems wrong, it is overwriting the set with only one inner map for the same key of the outer map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve readability and expresiveness of your code by using [`Map.forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) and [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-):

```
Map<Object, Set<Map<Object, String>>> map2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();

map1.forEach((key, setInfo) ->
    setInfo.forEach(inMap -> {
        if (inMap.containsKey("isMerge")) 
            map2.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new LinkedHashSet<>()).add(inMap);
    }));
```

Note: I've used `LinekdHashMap` and `LinkedHashSet` to preserve insertion order.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a more functional approach which makes the code a bit more readable in my opinion. But as the commenters already pointed out, you're never really going to get a simple, readable solution with such a data structure.

First I rewrote your function to be an actual function, i.e. take a value and return a value. Because what you are doing in the above is in essence taking one data structure and filtering it. In the code below I added your original function and added a more functional one as well. Please note I added Vavr as a dependency, see [Vavr](https://www.vavr.io) for more details (but only using it for the Tuple2 class so could easily be replaced with your own implementation).

```
package com.example.demo;

import io.vavr.Tuple2;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class LegacyDataStructure {
    public static Map<Object, Set<Map<Object,String>>> filteringFunction1(Map<Object, Set<Map<Object,String>>> origin) {
        Map<Object,Set<Map<Object,String>>> map2 = new HashMap<>();

        origin.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> {
            Set<Map<Object,String>> setInfo= e.getValue();
            setInfo.forEach(inMap -> {
                if(inMap.containsKey("isMerge")) {
                    HashSet<Map<Object,String>> set = new HashSet<>();
                    set.add(inMap);
                    map2.put(e.getKey(), set);
                }
            });
        });

        return map2;
    }

    public static Map<Object, Set<Map<Object, String>>> filteringFunction2(Map<Object, Set<Map<Object, String>>> origin) {
        return origin
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(e -> new Tuple2<>(
                                e.getKey(),
                                e.getValue()
                                        .stream()
                                        .filter(m -> m.containsKey("isMerge"))
                                        .collect(Collectors.toSet())
                        )
                )
                .filter(t -> t._2().size() > 0)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Tuple2::_1, Tuple2::_2));
    }
}
```

What you see happening in filteringFunction2 is that we take the entrySet and associate the keys with the values that match the criteria and filter out any of the keys that have zero matched criteria.

And here is a test to demonstrate that both functions are identical in what they yield:

```
package com.example.demo;

import io.vavr.Tuple2;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class FilteringTests {
    @Test
    public void bothFilteringMethodsShouldYieldSameResults() {
        Map<Object, Set<Map<Object,String>>> testMap = new HashMap<>();

        testMap.put(1, Set.of(Map.of("isMerge", "foo")));
        testMap.put(2, Set.of(Map.of("notMerge", "bar")));
        testMap.put(3, Set.of(Map.of("notMerge", "bar")));

        var results1 = LegacyDataStructure.filteringFunction1(testMap);
        var results2 = LegacyDataStructure.filteringFunction2(testMap);

        assertEquals(1, results1.keySet().size());
        assertEquals(1, results2.keySet().size());

        results1.entrySet().forEach(e -> {
            assertEquals(1, e.getKey());
            var tuple = extractFirstEntry(e.getValue());
            assertEquals("isMerge", tuple._1());
            assertEquals("foo", tuple._2());
        });

        results2.entrySet().forEach(e -> {
            assertEquals(1, e.getKey());
            var tuple = extractFirstEntry(e.getValue());
            assertEquals("isMerge", tuple._1());
            assertEquals("foo", tuple._2());
        });
    }

    private Tuple2<Object, String> extractFirstEntry(Set<Map<Object,String>> valueSet) {
        return valueSet
                .stream()
                .findFirst()
                .get()
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(m -> new Tuple2<>(m.getKey(), m.getValue()))
                .findFirst()
                .get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the **same** `setInfo` HashSet having **more than one** map that satisfies this condition?

If yes, your code is only copying the last of those maps as the previous one is getting replaced. So the code should be fixed as follows.

```
map1.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> {
    HashSet<Map<Object,String>> setInfo= e.getValue();

    HashSet<Map<Object, String>> set = new HashSet<>();
    setInfo.forEach(inMap -> {
        if (inMap.containsKey("isMerge")) {
            set.add(inMap);
        }
    });
    if (!set.isEmpty()) {
        map2.put(e.getKey(), set);
    }
});
```

Otherwise, if you have a guarantee that the **same** `setInfo` HashSet can have **only one** map that satisfies this condition, you can `break` the iteration of `setInfo` once such a map if found.

```
map1.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> {
    HashSet<Map<Object,String>> setInfo= e.getValue();
    for (Map<Object, String> inMap: setInfo) {
        if (inMap.containsKey("isMerge")) {
            HashSet<Map<Object, String>> set = new HashSet<>();
            set.add(inMap);
            map2.put(e.getKey(), set);
            break;
        }
    }
});
```